# edit xml layout params dynamically before inflate

Tags: android

I would like to change layout params like layout_weight dynamically before inflating the layout and setting the content view for an activity.  How would u do this?:

```
@Override
public void onCreate(final Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    //edit layout weight for some views in my layout here, before setting content view

    setContentView(R.layout.mylayout);

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I mean yes you can do it. By R.layout.mylayout you are just referencing to your layout resource. Just get a Layout object from that resource which might be like Layout mylayout = (Layout)findresourcebyid(R.layout.mylayout). After getting the reference you can change it dynamically and then inflate by setcontentview().